# How to measure the "volume" of each "Matryoshka doll" in a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, volume

Let $X$ be a (perfectly normal) topological space.

There is a family $\{C_i:i∈I\}$ indexed with an uncountable linear order $(I,\prec)$ such that $Ci\subset Cj$ whenever $i\prec j$. The boundaries of $C_i$ and $C_j$ does not intersect.

**Condition 1.** For any family defined above, there exists a "volume measure", which is a (continuous) real-valued function, $V(\cdot)$, such that $C_i\subset C_j\iff V(C_i)<V(C_j)$.

**Question.**  What are some necessary and/or sufficient topological conditions on $X$ of *Condition 1*?

For examples: one sufficient condition is $X$ being a metric space. To see this, let $1\in I$, then, for all $j$ define $V(C_j)=d(bd(C_j),C_1)-d(bd(C_1),C_j)$.

One necessary condition seems to be $T_6$.

Comment: What do you mean by $C_i \subseteq C_{i+1} \subseteq C_{i+2} \subseteq \ldots$ if $i \in I$ and $I$ is an arbitrary uncountable set?

Comment: @Adayah This is just a sequence of closed sets that contains all the prior sets, like Matryoshka dolls. Are there better ways to rigorize it?

Comment: If you just mean $C_1 \subseteq C_2 \subseteq C_3 \subseteq \ldots$, then $I = \mathbb{N}$ and it is not uncountable. If not, I don't know what you mean - a family $\{ C_i : i \in I \}$ indexed with an uncountable linear order $(I, \preccurlyeq)$ such that $C_i \subseteq C_j$ whenever $i \preccurlyeq j$ maybe?

Comment: @Adayah Sure, linear order works.

Comment: Next question: if $V$ is a function from $\{ C_i : i \in I \}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, what does it mean for it to be continuous? And a remark: in any case I highly doubt that the justification you gave for the condition to hold in metric spaces is correct. One reason is that boundaries of some of the sets may be empty, and there are probably many more. Also: do you assume that $I$ has the least element named $1$ in this argument?

Comment: @Adayah Your observations are pretty helpful. 1. I removed the requirement of continuous; 2. Boundaries can be empty: I missed that; probably I need to assume that the space is connected; 3. Yes let $1\in I$.

Comment: @Adayah Also, is it true that, in a metric space, the distance between any two sets are finite?

Comment: Condition 1. implies that the cofinality of $(I,\prec)$ must be countable — $\omega$ if there's no $\prec$-greatest $i\in I$. Suppose $(i_{\xi}\,|\, \xi\lt\alpha)$ is a strictly $\prec$-increasing sequence of elements of $I$. For $\xi \lt \xi + 1 \lt\alpha$, let $r_{\xi}$ be a rational in $(V(C_{i_{\xi}}), V(C_{i_{\xi+1}})$. Thus $\alpha$ must be countable.

Comment: More generally, $(I, \prec)$ can’t have any uncountable wellordered subsets.

Comment: Currently Condition 1 is equivalent to: "every chain of (closed?) subsets of $X$ with disjoint boundaries is order isomorphic to a subset of $(\mathbb{R}, \leqslant)$". Is that what you mean?

Comment: Your argument in metric spaces doesn't work even in connected spaces and I don't expect it to ever work at all without weird assumptions. Consider the following two examples. 1. For $r \geqslant 0$ let $C_r = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : -r \leqslant y \leqslant r \cdot e^{-x^2} \}$. Then $\{ C_r : r \geqslant 0 \}$ is a chain of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with disjoint boundaries, but $$d(\text{bd}(C_r), C_0) - d(\text{bd}(C_0), C_r) = 0$$ for all $r \geqslant 0$.

Comment: 2. Let $X = [0, 3]$ with metric induced by the injection $i : X \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $i(t) = (\cos \frac{\pi t}{2}, \sin \frac{\pi t}{2})$, so $X$ is essentialy three quarters of a circle. For $t \in [0, 2)$ let $C_t = [0, t]$ and let $C_2 = [0, 2] \cup \{ 3 \}$. Then the function $V(t) = d(\text{bd}(C_t), C_0) - d(\text{bd}(C_0), C_t)$ satisfies $V(2) = V(1) < V(1.5)$, so $V$ is not increasing.

Comment: @Adayah Many thanks for the comments. In the counterexample, I think the boundaries of $C_t$ intersect at $"0"$; but I believe a slight twist of the example will still work. I probably need to assume that $C_i$ must be connected sets.

Comment: The boundaries don't intersect because $0 \in \text{int}(C_t)$ for $t > 0$ - in the relative topology of $X = [0, 3]$ the interval $[0, t)$ is an open set. Anyway, when you finish fixing your question I might be interested in giving it a shot.

Comment: @Adayah. Can "Matrioshaka doll" (a family  ${Ci:i∈I}$ indexed with an uncountable linear order $(I,≼)$ such that ${Ci⊆Cj}$) serve as an illustrative example of a fiber bundle? The doll would be the fiber, a two-manifold, and its surface area, an intrinsic property, the base.